# (Asp.NET MVC) using static connection?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

```
using ( SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection ("ConnectionString") )
{

   con.Open();

   ..........

}
```

Instead of the above example, I use the following code. Does using a static connection cause a memory problem?

```
public static class

{


   static SqlConnection con;
   static string connectionString = "......";

   public static method

   {

      con = SqlConnection(connectionString);

      con.Open();

   }

}
```

Thank you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that's a good approach for 2 reasons:

1. You have to make sure of closing your connection after using it.
2. Because of 1, you could run into concurrency issues, for instance, only 1 DataReader can use a connection at a time, so if you're executing 2 pages at a time it would fail. You could also close that connection while another page is using it.

So, all in all, don't do that.